# Subset data frame in R based on matching multiple ranges for multiple variables

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a problem that seems kind of similar to some previously asked questions on SO, but different enough that I can't quite figure out an elegant solution.

I have a set of real data that I need to match to a database of theoretical values. I'd like to filter based on multiple sets of multiple conditions. For example, if I have the following data.frame of theoretical values,

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(10,13,16,22,28,30), y=c(1:6))
> df
   x y
1 10 1
2 13 2
3 16 3
4 22 4
5 28 5
6 30 6
```

and I have the following real data,

```
realdata <- data.frame(x=c(10.05, 13.06, 22.01),y=c(1.02, 1.99, 3.96))
> realdata
      x    y
1 10.05 1.02
2 13.06 1.99
3 22.01 3.96
```

I can easily search for which theoretical rows correspond to rows in my real data one at a time with something like this:

```
tolerance <- .10
subset(df, x>(realdata[1,1]-tolerance) & x<(realdata[1,1]+tolerance) & 
+ y>(realdata[1,2]-tolerance) & y<(realdata[1,2]+tolerance))
subset(df, x>(realdata[2,1]-tolerance) & x<(realdata[2,1]+tolerance) & 
+ y>(realdata[2,2]-tolerance) & y<(realdata[2,2]+tolerance))
#...etc for each row of real data
```

But is there any way to do this for all the rows in my real data without writing a loop? Basically, I want to find all the theoretical rows that correspond to any one of the rows in my real data, within a given tolerance. In reality, my theoretical and real tables have hundreds of thousands of observations, and this is something I do quite a bit, so speed will matter, I think.

Also, if anyone knows a way of determining whether a value is within a range using a single expression that works inside subset(), that would be icing on the cake. Maybe subset is the wrong function to be using, though, in which case never mind.

Comment: Aside: In general, you want to stay away from `subset` and use `[` instead, especially if you're programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outer` to calculate all pairwise differences between `df` and `realdata` and examine if both `x` and `y` are less than the tolerance

```
tolerance <- .10

# x
xx <- abs(outer(df$x, realdata$x, "-")) < tolerance
# y
yy <- abs(outer(df$y, realdata$y, "-")) < tolerance

# if both are within the tolerance the sum of xx and yy will be 2
(mat <- xx + yy > 1)
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So the first column of `mat` shows which rows of `df` are within the tolerance (in this case the first).

Rather inelegantly return the row of matches in df in the order of the rows of `realdata`

```
lapply(1:ncol(mat), function(i) df[mat[,i], ])

# return all matched data
df[row(mat)[mat], ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a implicit loop with a vectorized test:

```
 apply( realdata, 1, 
       function(x)  abs( x[1] - df[,1] ) < tolerance & 
                     abs( x[2] - df[,2]) <tolerance )
 #------------------------
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

This does it with no apply functions:

```
> kronecker( as.matrix(df), as.matrix(realdata), function(x,y) { abs(x -y) <tolerance} )[,c(1,4)]
       [,1]  [,2]
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,] FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE
[10,] FALSE FALSE
[11,] FALSE FALSE
[12,]  TRUE  TRUE
[13,] FALSE FALSE
[14,] FALSE FALSE
[15,] FALSE FALSE
[16,] FALSE FALSE
[17,] FALSE FALSE
[18,] FALSE FALSE
```

You can consolidate it with rowSums(.) == 2